# Is there a function to get the caption for an image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, captions

I'm trying to get the captions from images in Wordpress but I can't find an easy function to grab this bit of information.

Anyone know a way to get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out captions are stored as post excerpts.  So,

```
<?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?>
```

will print out the caption if you are on the attachment image page (image.php in your theme) and inside the Loop.

Answer (score 19):

If you are trying to get the caption while in a post you can echo it out inside your "the_post_thumbnail" tag.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?>
```

You can also use the same method to show the image description.  This is a little better feature in WordPress 3.5

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content; ?>
```

If you need to style the caption or description you can wrap it in a div like below.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '<div class="myDiv">' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt . '</div>'
; ?>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using Wordpress 4.8, this little guy worked for me:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail_caption(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code, It works fine.

```
$get_description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; if(!empty($get_description)){//If description is not empty show the div    echo '<div class="img-caption">' . $get_description . '</div>'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside figure tag of your single.php file

```
$image_caption = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;
if(!empty($image_caption)) { 
    echo '<figcaption itemprop="caption">' . $image_caption . '</figcaption>'; 
}
```